# How can I use created pivot table from SQL Server in C# ASP.NET MVC Razor Html table?

Tags: c#, pivot

I created a pivot table via SQL Server and I want to use it in ASP.NET MVC using C#. I have already looked at examples but mine is something different than examples in the internet. I want to list table as see photo that I have attached. Can someone help with this?

[image: Pivot Table Image]

Comment: _"I want to list table as see photo that I have attached"_ - so what's stopping you?

Comment: *"but mine is something different than examples"* - Different how?  What examples?  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: I mean different is normally by pivot tables examples on internet are 1 column summary but here by mine example is  columns.

Comment: @David I have tried and if I pivot table as datatable view in razor it works but footer totals not. Maybe this table convert to list on code behind or arraylist but how?

Comment: @Emin, you question is not clear yet! Please write about your data and behind code and what you tried in code before.

Comment: @RAM I have done it as answer. My question is How can I calculate / sum footer total of columns and grand total? Thanks.

Comment: @Emin, You can write an answer for yourself but you can not write a question as an answer else you get negative scores! Please copy your answer and append it to the question first. If you familiar with jQuery you can add some class to your table cells and use it similar **[the answer I have written here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474983/calculate-total-value-using-jquery/48475260#48475260)** before. Although you can calculate them server-side too.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this in steps but I can not calculating total balance of rows and columns.

First I've created views and stored procedure for pivotting.
[Sql Query and pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C07Zr.jpg)

Then by c# I call procedure

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Utils.Utils2 util = new Utils.Utils2(); // My class for connection
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();       
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

        connetionString = conString;
        connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "spPivotTest";

        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        connection.Close();

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        table = dataset.Tables[0];


         ViewData["PivotDataTable"] = table;

        return View();
    }
```

And Razor view code is here

@{

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
tbl = ViewData["PivotDataTable"] as DataTable;


List<String> columns = new List<String>();

for (int c = 0; c < tbl.Columns.Count; c++)
{
    string colname = tbl.Columns[c].Caption.ToString();

    if (colname.Contains("_"))
    {
        columns.Add(colname.Substring(0, colname.IndexOf("_")));
    }
    else
    {
        columns.Add(colname);
    }
}

List<String> cols = new List<String>();
cols = columns.Distinct().ToList();
```

}

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="example1">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" class="text-center"><b>CUSTOMERS</b></td>
        @for (int i = 1; i < cols.Count; i++)
        {

            <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup" class="text-center">@cols[i]</th>
        }
        <th rowspan="1" scope="colgroup" class="text-center">TOTAL</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < cols.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            int sira = i + 1;

            <th scope="col">DEBT</th>
            <th scope="col">CREDIT</th>
            <th scope="col" style="background-color:azure">BALANCE</th>
        }
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>


    @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
    {


        <tr>

            @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.ToString()))
                {
                    <td>0.00</td>
                }
                else
                {

                    <td>@cell</td>
                }


            }

        </tr>


    }

</tbody>
```

Output
[enter image Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWFsi.jpg)

Comment: I'll calculate footer totals and rows total balance. How can I do?